# Excel VBA: How to combat Runtime Error 1004: Method 'Range' of object'_Worksheet' failed?

Tags: vba, excel

I have written code that allows me to perform a vlookup in the next available column, and then multiplies the results of the vlookup by the values in the last used column(1 to the left). It seemed to be working fine, until today when I keep getting:

> "error 1004: Method 'Range' of Object'_Worksheet' failed"

Here is my code:

```
Sub vlookup5()
   Dim SourceLastRow As Long
        Dim OutputLastRow As Long
        Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
        Dim outputSheet As Worksheet

        Dim NextColumn As Long
        Dim ColumnStr As String
         Dim ColumnStr2 As String
          Dim ColumnStr3 As String
        Set sourceSheet = Worksheets("Data1")
        Set outputSheet = Worksheets("Pivot")
        With sourceSheet
             SourceLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        End With

        With outputSheet
            NextColumn = .Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
            If NextColumn + 1 < 27 Then
               ColumnStr = Chr(64 + NextColumn + 1)
            Else
                ColumnStr = Chr(64 + Int((NextColumn + 1) / 26)) & Chr(64 + ((NextColumn + 1) Mod 26))
            End If
            If NextColumn - 1 < 27 Then
               ColumnStr3 = Chr(64 + NextColumn - 1)
            Else
                ColumnStr3 = Chr(64 + Int((NextColumn - 1) / 26)) & Chr(64 + ((NextColumn - 1) Mod 26))
            End If
            If NextColumn < 27 Then
               ColumnStr2 = Chr(64 + NextColumn)
            Else
                ColumnStr2 = Chr(64 + Int((NextColumn) / 26)) & Chr(64 + ((NextColumn) Mod 26))
            End If
            OutputLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row - 1

            .Range(Cells(4, NextColumn), Cells(OutputLastRow, NextColumn)).Formula = _
                 "=VLOOKUP(D4,'" & sourceSheet.Name & "'!$A$2:$H$" & SourceLastRow & ",6,0)*1000" & "*" & ColumnStr3 & 4
            DoEvents
            .Cells(OutputLastRow + 1, NextColumn).Formula = "=SUM(" & ColumnStr2 & "4:" & ColumnStr2 & OutputLastRow & ")"
        End With
        End Sub
```

I keep getting the error on this line:

```
.Range(Cells(4, NextColumn), Cells(OutputLastRow, NextColumn)).Formula = _
                 "=VLOOKUP(D4,'" & sourceSheet.Name & "'!$A$2:$H$" & SourceLastRow & ",6,0)*1000" & "*" & ColumnStr3 & 4
```

Comment: instead of finding the letter just use Cells: so instead of `& ColumnStr3 & 4` use `& .Cells(4,NextColumn).Address(0,0)`

Comment: `.Range(.Cells(4, NextColumn), .Cells(OutputLastRow, NextColumn)).Formula...`   Without the leading period, Cells() in a regular module will refer to the ActiveSheet (not necessarily outputSheet)

Comment: I tried both of those both individually and together and keep getting the same error message

Comment: You need to use what @TimWilliams stated and I think you want `+ 1` on this line `OutputLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row - 1`.  `-1` moves it up and if `.Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row` returns row 1 then it will be 0 and there is no row at `0`  Which would give you an error on that line.

Comment: @TimWilliams That line gets me the last used row in column D. and that line was working when I first applied it. The whole code worked, until I added the same code in another subfunction after this one... but they don't have anything to do with each other so I don't understand why this error came up all of a sudden??

Comment: If you change your workflow such that a different sheet is now active when you're running a particular piece of code, this can cause the type of error you're seeing.  This is why it's so important - if you want "robust" code - to always qualify every call to Range() and Cells() with a worksheet object.

Comment: i do not want to criticize your effort, but where did you find the code that got you started?  it is absolutely a place to stay away from.  ....  do web search for "vba different ways to address excel range"  ... one very good hit:   http://excelmatters.com/referring-to-ranges-in-vba/